# Configure Jira & Confluence together with Boncode

Tags: jira, ajp, confluence

I have Jira set up on `MyServer:8080/Jira` and Confluence  on `MyServer:8090/Wiki`

I'm trying to achieve the folowing

MyServer/Jira -> forward to Jira 
and 
MyServer/Wiki -> forward to Confluence

For that, I've set up `BonCode` 'thingy' witch works perfectly fine with a single forward. (for example `MyServer/jira` -> forwards all requests to a 'AJP Connector on 8009')

Question is - how do I get BonCode connector to work on 2 ports (8009 for Jira and 8010 for Confluence)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that you have not done a global install. Uninstall if you have done so, and reinstall in site specific mode.
Install the connector for each site you wish to use.
Inside the IIS site where different path need to target different Tomcat instances create empty IIS Applications with matching names for subpaths, e.g.

- jira
- Wiki

see -- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772042(v=ws.10).aspx

Inside each application create empty 'BIN' directory.
Copy files from main site's BIN directory. 
Open the BonCodeAJP13.settings for each subpath and change port and server.
Add handlers to each application if not already inherited from main site.

That should do it.